# How do I properly implement Android's SharedPreferences?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I want to save input values so that they can be recalled when the application is restarted. Using [this tutorial](http://android-er.blogspot.com/2011/01/example-of-using-sharedpreferencesedito.html) as a guide. I wrote the following code but am not having success getting the values to be recalled.  Any help is greatly appreciated thank you.

Save Preferences method

```
public void SavePreferences(String key, String value){
    SharedPreferences portfoliopreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = portfoliopreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(key, value);
    editor.commit();
}
```

Save Preferences input

```
if(users.contains(usernull)){
    pn1 = enterportfolioname.getText().toString();
    denomination1 = denomination;  
    portfoliocurrency1 = portfoliocurrency;
    user1 = new PortfolioRecord(pn1, denomination1+df.format(portfoliovalue1));
    users.remove(usernull);
    users.add(user1);
    portfoliosdelete.add(pn1); 
    adapterdeletetype.notifyDataSetChanged();
    portfoliolist.invalidateViews();
    SavePreferences("U1C", "ýes");
    SavePreferences("PN1", enterportfolioname.getText().toString());
    SavePreferences("DN1", denomination);
    SavePreferences("PC1", "usd");
}
```

Load Preferences

```
public void LoadPreferences(){
    SharedPreferences portfoliopreferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String isuser1created = portfoliopreferences.getString("U1C", "");
    if(isuser1created.equals("yes")){           
        String savedportfolioname = portfoliopreferences.getString("PN1", "");
        String saveddenomination = portfoliopreferences.getString("DN1", "");
        String savedporfoliocurrency = portfoliopreferences.getString("PC1", ""); 
        pn1 = savedportfolioname;
        denomination1 = saveddenomination;
        portfoliocurrency1 = currencyUSD;
        user1 = new PortfolioRecord(pn1, denomination1+portfoliovalue1);        
        users.add(user1);
        portfoliosdelete.add(pn1); 
        calculateportfoliovalue1();
        adapterdeletetype.notifyDataSetChanged();
        portfoliolist.invalidateViews();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is simply that "ýes" does not equal "yes":

```
SavePreferences("U1C", "ýes");
...
if(isuser1created.equals("yes"))
```

So you never execute the code inside this block... (Change one or the other.)

---

Also you create a new `editor` and run `commit()` each time you want to save one value. While it executes, this is slower than necessary.

You should keep a class wide reference to `portfoliopreferences` and only call `commit()` once:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = portfoliopreferences.edit();
editor.putString("U1C", "ýes");
editor.putString("PN1", enterportfolioname.getText().toString());
editor.putString("DN1", denomination);
editor.putString("PC1", "usd");
editor.commit();
```

And you create Strings to that one don't use:

```
String savedportfolioname = portfoliopreferences.getString("PN1", "");
String saveddenomination = portfoliopreferences.getString("DN1", "");
...
pn1 = savedportfolioname;
denomination1 = saveddenomination;
```

You can skip over these:

```
pn1 = portfoliopreferences.getString("PN1", "");
denomination1 = portfoliopreferences.getString("DN1", "");
```